# MapBox(IOS): How to add animated gif image on map?

Tags: swift, mapbox

I need to display animated GIF's on map-box map.
Below is the code I have tried with `MGLSymbolStyleLayer`, but it's not working.

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "myImage.gif")
        mapView.style?.setImage(image!, forName: "mygifImage")

    let gifSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "gif-source", features: pointFeatureArray, options: nil)
        myMapView.style?.addSource(gifSource)

    let gifLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "symbol-layer", source: gifSource)
        gifLayer.iconImageName = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: "mygifImage")
        myMapView.style?.addLayer(gifLayer)
```

Can some one help me how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS does not currently have built-in support for animated GIF with [style layers](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10595). For now, the workaround is to split your GIF into frames and use [`-setImage:forName:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Classes/MGLStyle.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLStyle(im)setImage:forName:) to add the image to the style. Then use that to create a `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` and update the `iconImageName` property on a timer.

It may be more performant to use [`MGLImageSource`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Classes/MGLImageSource.html). Instead of updating the `iconImageName` property on the symbol style layer, update the `image` property on the image source. I noticed that CPU usage was lower when I used `MGLImageSource` than when I used a `MGLSymbolStyleLayer`. Both of these approaches apply to a single animated gif. I have not tested either with multiple gifs.

Comment: I have noticed that mapbox don't have an option to add multiple MGLImageSource. Is that correct?.

Comment: Also the workaround you mentioned is causing more CPU usage and battery consumption, resulting of heating the devices.

Comment: You can add multiple image sources to a style, but you can't add multiple images to an image source. We have discussed [supporting animated gifs](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10594) with image source, but do not have a timeline for that feature.